# Looking for an elegant mode of getting the lefmost part of a string, with Java

Tags: java, string

I want to return "https://rumpelstiltskin.com:7071/service/admin" from "https://rumpelstiltskin.com:7071/service/admin/soap"

I'm doing like this:

```
String str="https://rumpelstiltskin.com:7071/service/admin/soap";
String strOut="";
strOut=str.split("/soap")[0];
System.out.println(strOut);
```

Is there a more elegant way to do that?

Comment: You could use `substring(int, int)`, but I don't know that it's any more elegant.

Comment: The last path will always be soap, in lowercase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about the following using [`String#replace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29):

```
String str = "https://rumpelstiltskin.com:7071/service/admin/soap";
String newString = str.replace("/soap", "");
System.out.println(newString);
```

Output is (tried and tested):

```
https://rumpelstiltskin.com:7071/service/admin
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
 String str="https://rumpelstiltskin.com:7071/service/admin/soap";
 String newStr = str.substring(0,str.lastIndexOf("/"));
 System.out.println(newStr);
```

Comment: That would be my answer but it don't answered my comment if it wants to check for soap on the url path

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:-

```
 String str = "https://rumpelstiltskin.com:7071/service/admin/soap";
 String s = str.replace("/soap", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String str="https://rumpelstiltskin.com:7071/service/admin/soap";
String strOut= str.substring(0, str.lastIndexOf("/"));
```

Only works if, as asked the last chunk is always /soap

Comment: Yes it would. I should be more clear on what I meant in relation to the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

```
String str="https://rumpelstiltskin.com:7071/service/admin/soap";
String strOut=str.substring(0, str.lastIndexOf("/soap"));
System.out.println(strOut);
```